# How to use mt940 gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mt940

Hi I have installed mt940 gem file and trying to access its methods as follows

```
require 'mt940'
#require 'mt940_parser'


class HomePageController < ApplicationController

  def aboutus
    #read all the files
     Dir.foreach(directory_path) do |item|
      puts item + "\n"
      MT940::Base.transactions(item)

      end

     end


 end
```

but um getting an error

```
NameError in HomePageController#aboutus
uninitialized constant MT940::Base
```

Um quite new to ruby on rails and I do not have a clue about it. If any one can help thank you

Comment: have you run bundle install and restarted your server ??

Comment: Well I done that but it gives me same error

Comment: Did you add `gem 'mt940'` to `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes I ve added and did a bundle install and update

Comment: Just checked it on my computer -- it works. (windows 7 + ruby 1.9.3 + sinatra 1.4.3 + mt940 0.6.6)

Comment: not working here dont know what has gone wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also included MT940 parser gem along with MT940. Because of that I got a different implementation and once I removed MT940 parser it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Which gem are you using? some of the MT940 gems have a bit of a wired namespace and needs to required differently.

shameless promotion :) 
you might want to look into Cmxl - your friendly [MT940 parser](https://github.com/railslove/cmxl): https://github.com/railslove/cmxl